# Active Admin: undefined method `title' in controller#update and #create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, activeadmin

When I want to edit an entry of my resource or create a new one I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError in Admin::HotelRoomsController#update 
undefined method `title' for #<HotelRoom:0x00000004a67f30>
```

I have no idea why.

I hope someone can help!

Here's my model:

```
class HotelRoom < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, :presence => true
  self.table_name = "hotel_room"

  belongs_to :hotel, :foreign_key => 'H_ID'
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :hotel
```

Comment: Please share some more code to illustrate the problem

Comment: The thing is I don't have much code to share because it's generated by active admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG I'm so dumb ... of course it's validation and there's no title attribute for my model. Copied it wrong I guess.